# Trouble with creating export control for Sitefinity widget using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

I am working on the Controller class for an MVC-based Sitefinity widget that is meant to get all page content and export it to JSON format for later use. The problem is that, when I try to add to the pageArray variable, I get an error in Visual Studio: The best overload method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(System.Web.UI.Page)' has some invalid arguments. I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

Here is the function as it appears in the ExportController class:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        List<Page> pageArray = new List<Page>();

        //// Use Sitefinity API get all pages
        IQueryable<PageNode> pageNodes = App.WorkWith().Pages().Where(pN => (pN.Page != null && pN.Page.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live)).Get();
        foreach (var page in pageNodes) 
           pageArray.Add(page);//this is where I get the error message  

        return Json(pageArray, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I will admit I am new to both ASP.NET MVC and the Sitefinity API, and I am trying to learn both as quickly as possible for a project I'm working on.

Comment: You should also always check the Visible property for True, otherwise it may include deleted items that are in the Recycle Bin, e.g. add this to the Where clause:

&& pN.Visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the pageArray from System.Web.UI.Page to Telerik.Sitefinity.Pages.Model.PageNode

Depending on which version of Sitefinity that you are using.  Since version 7.0 the metadata information which was previously located in PageData is now located in PageNode.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    List<PageNode> pageArray = new List<PageNode>();

    //// Use Sitefinity API get all pages
    IQueryable<PageNode> pageNodes = App.WorkWith().Pages().Where(pN => (pN.Page != null && pN.Page.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live)).Get();
    foreach (var page in pageNodes) 
       pageArray.Add(page);

    return Json(pageArray, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fluent API or can use Native API like below

```
var pageManager = PageManager.GetManager();
            pageManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;

            var rootPages = pageManager.GetPageNodes()
                                       .AsEnumerable()
                                       .Where(p => !p.IsBackend && p.Parent != null && p.Parent.Title.ToLower() == "pages" && p.ShowInNavigation && p.ApprovalWorkflowState == "Published")                    
                                       .OrderBy(p => p.Ordinal)
                                       .ToList();
```